# how to change the content of mat expansion panel header when in expanded mode

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change the contents of mat expansion panel header when it is expanded, and when collapsed returns to previous state.

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <div>{{'my name is joe'}}</div>
        <div>{{'i am 20 years old'}}</div>
        // when expanded i want to hide the second div and change
        // the style of first div margin, padding e.t.c
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    // ....
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a template variable and the property `expanded` of the `mat-expansion-panel` like this:

**Template**

```
<mat-expansion-panel #panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div [ngClass]="{'first-div': panel.expanded}">Always shown</div>
    <div *ngIf="!panel.expanded">Not shown when expanded</div>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  Content here
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

**CSS**

```
.first-div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-vwyn43?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) that hides the second `div` when expanded and applies a CSS class to the first one.